# AJAX query returns 504 error after 60 seconds

Tags: javascript, ajax, nginx

I am trying to run php scripts that take 100 seconds or more to run. But during testing, my AJAX query automatically triggers a 504 error after 60 seconds on the dot. I have already increased every "maximum_execution_time" type values in the php settings and the TimeOut value is set to 120. I also don't use Amazon AWS so Load Balancing limtis arent an issue. How do i solve this?

ajax:

```
$.ajax({
              type: 'GET',
              url: post_url, 
              data: post_data,
              success: function(msg) {
              $("#loading").hide();
              $(box).fadeOut(0, function(){
              box.html(msg).fadeIn(0);
              });
              },
              error: function(xmlhttprequest, textstatus, message) {
        if(textstatus==="timeout") {
            alert("got timeout");
        } else {
            alert(textstatus);
        }
    }
          });
```

php:

```
include 'connect.php';


sleep(90);

$sql2 =  "SELECT * FROM pwdreset WHERE r_id = 1";
        if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql2)) {
            header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
        echo "theres a connection!";
        } else {
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
            header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true");
        echo "no connection";
        }
```

Comment: Possibly the 504 comes from your reverse proxy (nginx, Caddy, Apache, whatever you use) and not PHP.

Comment: @CherryDT apparently i have both nginx and apache on my VPS server, what should i look for specifically in regards to my issue?

Comment: I think if you are hitting a 60s limit you are doing something wrong anyway... There has to be a more reliable way to do what you need.

Comment: @CherryDT what other way is there? bear in mind that i need to return the values from the php function, not simply run the php function in the background.

Comment: There can be a database table for long-running tasks and their status, which can be polled to find out when the result is available.

Comment: @CherryDT Ok, I found a method for that using xhttp. But does that method guarantee that no time limit will be applied if a task takes a long time to complete and update its status?

Answer (score 0):

By default, maximum execution time in php is 30 second. If your php script runs more than 30 it will return 504 HTTP status stating maximum execution timeout.

As you mentioned you have already changed your setting in php.ini file.
You can try setting  `ini_set('max_execution_time', '0'):` in your php first line which takes more time. It will allow the script to run infinitely.

But you should optimize your script to run below 120 seconds and remove the maximum execution time zero.

Comment: my scripts already run longer than 30 seconds so i think my php settings are working. It's AJAX that is breaking the script after 60 seconds.